# How to load the default theme on template_include action hook in Wordpress WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

Im currently using the "template_include" action hook to load a custom store manager template for WooCommerce but I also want to load the default theme for any other user but for now it goes blank

```
//store manager action hook
add_action( 'template_include', 'checkStoreManagerTemplate' );

function checkStoreManagerTemplate(){
    
    global $wp;
    $wp->parse_request();
    $current_url = home_url($wp->request);
    $home_url = get_site_url();
    
    $urls = explode($home_url, $current_url);
    
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $role = $user->roles[0];
    
    if(strpos($urls[1], '/store-manager') == 0 && $role == 'wc_product_vendors_admin_vendor'){
        require_once get_theme_file_path('page-templates/store-manager.php');
        exit;
    }
    else{
        //I want to load the default theme for normal users
    }
}
```

I need to load the default theme in the "else" section. Bt I cant seem to find the code for it.

Btw if there is a better way of implementing this Im also open to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `template_include` is actually a `filter`, not an `action`. Test the following code:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'ywp_check_stock_manager_template' );
function ywp_check_stock_manager_template( $template ) {
    global $wp;

    $wp->parse_request();

    $current_url    = home_url( $wp->request );
    $home_url       = get_site_url();
    $urls           = explode( $home_url, $current_url );

    if( strpos( $urls[1], '/shop' ) == 0 && current_user_can( 'wc_product_vendors_admin_vendor' ) ) {
        $template = include( 'page-templates/store-manager.php' );
    }

    return $template;
}
```